# Refresh All not triggering QueryTable's BeforeRefresh event - why?

Tags: vba, excel, events, triggers

As stated in a title: I've found out that clicking "Refresh All" button on a ribbon doesn't trigger QueryTable's BeforeRefresh event. Why is it so? Is there a way to change this behavior?

The strange thing is that AfterRefresh event of the very same QueryTable is triggered perfectly!

To analyze this behavior I've created two tables in two worksheets:

1. Simple, unlinked table called `Source`
2. Table called `Destination` linked to `Source` table. Connection was created using Microsoft Query and Excel Files as Data source.

Then, I've created `TestClass` as follows:

```
Option Explicit

Private WithEvents qt As QueryTable

Public Sub Init(pQt As QueryTable)
    Set qt = pQt
End Sub

Private Sub qt_BeforeRefresh(Cancel As Boolean)
    MsgBox "BeforeRefresh"
End Sub

Private Sub qt_AfterRefresh(ByVal Success As Boolean)
    MsgBox "AfterRefresh"
End Sub
```

Finally, I've created, initialized and stored an instance of `TestClass`.

Right-clicking `Destination` table and choosing "Refresh" gives expected results: MsgBox is displayed twice, confirming that both Before- and After- Refresh events were triggered.

However, clicking "Refresh All" on ribbon results in only one MsgBox being displayed: AfterRefresh one.

I've prepared a minimal Excel file that reproduces described behavior. It is available for download here: [RefreshAllNotTriggeringBeforeRefresh.xlsm](https://mega.nz/#!eIZWgQbI!tK5kIEW8E2Qfyj7-7J6agP18Ncap8CRaJdJnaAl5Pes)

**EDIT 1**: In response to [Rik Sportel's question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44531126/refresh-all-not-triggering-querytables-beforerefresh-event-why#comment76067677_44531126) on how `TestClass` instance is being created and initialized.

Here's a relevant part of `ThisWorkbook` object:

```
Option Explicit

Private Destination As New TestClass

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Destination.Init WS_Destination.ListObjects("Destination").QueryTable
End Sub
```

Where `WS_Destination` is a value for a `(Name)` property of a worksheet containing `Destination` table.

As one can see, `Destination` is a private field, but it *seems* that garbage collector doesn't care: I can right-click refresh `Destination` table as many times as I want and both Before- and After- MsgBoxes *always* pop up. Whereas, Refresh All *never* (not even once) triggers BeforeRefresh event, yet *always* triggers AfterRefresh one.

Comment: Is your initialized instance of TestClass a public variable outside of the test script that initializes it? If not, it will be destroyed by the garbage collector as soon as the script finishes.

Comment: @RikSportel I've edited my question and added more details that answer your comment. However, I'm afraid that garbage collector isn't a problem in this case.

Comment: See answer - This is default behavior. Your second question "Is there a way to change this behavior?" - Well, no. Not for this event. You could create something custom around it of course. However, what do you wish to achieve?

Comment: I'd like to implement a custom logic on how tables are growing/shrinking as a result of a change in source data. Excel provides 3 solutions: inserting/deleting cells, inserting/deleting table rows and overwriting/clearing existing cells. None of them fits my needs. Long story short: my idea is to insert/delete *entire* worksheet rows, thus I need to catch both Before- (to insert new blank rows in case table grows)  and After- (to delete excessive rows) events.

Comment: Use the workbook's SheetChange events and store the old sizes when initializing the workbook.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Option Explicit
Public tc as TestClass
Sub Test()
    Set tc = New TestClass
    tc.Init Worksheets("SomeSheet").ListObjects(1).QueryTable
End Sub
```

- The BeforeRefresh only triggers when you use the refresh option in the **Table** tab Excel GUI. When you use this one, both events trigger appropriately.
- When you use the refresh option in the **Query** tab of the Excel GUI, only the second event triggers.

The reason is that the QueryTable **does not** have this BeforeRefresh event triggered when using the Query refresh option, is because you're not actually refreshing the QueryTable itself, but the underlying Query.

- The BeforeRefresh event occurs before any refreshes of the **query table**. [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff823150.aspx)
- The AfterRefresh event occurs after the **query** is completed or cancelled. [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835922.aspx)

When you do:

```
Option Explicit
Public tc as TestClass
Sub Test()
    Set tc = New TestClass
    tc.Init Worksheets("SomeSheet").ListObjects(1).QueryTable
    Worksheets("SomeSheet").ListObjects(1).QueryTable.Refresh
End Sub
```

You'll see that both events trigger appropriately.

**Edit:** RefreshAll actually refreshes the queries in the workbook, not the querytables. The same answer applies.

In short: It's behaving as expected.

Comment: Well, that explains everything. Well, *almost* everything. I've noticed that Excel's behavior varies depending on how you order "Refresh all" command. Physically clicking on "Refresh All" button within Data tab on Ribbon doesn't trigger Before event. Yet, calling `ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll` from Immediate window or even pushing Ctrl+Alt+F5 (shortcut suggested by Excel itself) **does** trigger BeforeRefresh event. Do you know why is it so, by any chance?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken the VBA ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll refreshes all Connections, PivotCaches, PivotTables, QueryTables, etc. Whereas the ribbon button refreshes the connections only. I'd have to check this though.

Comment: ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll: Refreshes **all external data ranges and PivotTable reports** in the specified workbook, from MSDN. Thus, this includes QueryTables.